# De-weeding a raised bed

Tags: weed-control, raised-beds

I build this raised bed about 4 months ago. The bottom of the bed is in contact with earth and judging by the length of the weeds the weeds might be growing all the way up and through from the ground.

Is there any point in trying to pull out these weeds? As they are so long they feel like they snap in the middle; rather than all coming out.

I've been reading up on better ways to prevent weeds for future beds but is there any thing I can do to try save the soil? I would guess its going to be pretty weedy going forward.

[image: Weeds in a raised bed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the soil below your bed contained a rich store of weed seeds at the time of installation, then it is entirely possible to have them germinating and growing through the bed - especially when the raised bed is only a few inches tall. Assuming the soil you put into the bed is relatively weed-free, you would simply need to remove weeds before they go to seed until the pre-existing supply is exhausted. In such a small space this should be a manageable endeavor. I would try to get to them before they grow as large as the weeds shown in the photo so that they don't build up enough energy stores in the roots to regrow if they break during removal.

By doing this, you will soon deplete the store of existing weed seeds and then only have to deal with seeds introduced from above.